# convert ceilometer output to python dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, openstack, ceilometer

I'm a little new to Python and openstack ceilometer. I'm reading ceilometer data using the following code:

```
import ceilometerclient.client

cclient = ceilometerclient.client.get_client(2, os_username="Ceilometeradmin", os_password="blahblah", os_tenant_name="blahblah", os_auth_url="http://xxx.xx.xx.x:5000/v2.0")

query = [dict(field='resource_id', op='eq', value='dd893564-85e5-43f8-a384-086417f1d82c')]

ls = cclient.meters.list(q=query)
```

(Please see picture of output attached)

[image]

Does anyone know how i could convert this into a dataframe?

I tried : `ls2 = pandas.DataFrame(ls, columns=["user_id", "name", "resource_id", "source", "meter_id", "project_id", "type", "unit"])`

but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 250, in init copy=copy)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 363, in _init_ndarray return create_block_manager_from_blocks([values.T], [columns, index])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3750, in create_block_manager_from_blocks construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3732, in construction_error passed,implied))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (8, 2)
```

if someone could help it would really be much much appreciated..

Thank you

Best Wishes 
T

Comment: If the <Meter part was not there (i.e. if you had a list of dicts), your code would work.

Comment: I tried removing it with ls[ls.index("[<Meter ")] = "'" but it throws and error:

Comment: what is type(ls[0])?

Comment: Also, what happens when you do ls2 = pandas.DataFrame(ls)? (This will give you an insight as to why you got that ValueError)

Comment: it's a list type; it returns this when i try to convert to pandas.dataframe:                                                    0
0  <Meter {u'user_id': u'f82bcc547ffd4bf0ae28c452...
1  <Meter {u'user_id': u'f82bcc547ffd4bf0ae28c452...

Comment: not sure what it means?

Comment: I'm a bit busy atm but it's possible to use `DataFrame.from_items` with a generator. Will post an answer soon

Answer (score 1):

With the help of a colleague we managed to find the solution. 
I'm posting it in case it's useful to anyone trying to convert ceilometer data into a dataframe.

```
ls2 = str(ls)[8:-2]
tmp = ls2.replace("u'","'")
tmp = tmp.replace("<Meter","")
tmp = tmp.replace("}>","}")
tmp= "["+tmp+"]"
tmp = tmp.replace("'", "\"")
parsed = json.loads(tmp)
ls3 = pandas.DataFrame(parsed)
```

Replaced characters which make it as invalid dictionary and converted into dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
meters = c.meters.list()
fields = ['user_id', 'name', 'resource_id', 'source', 'meter_id', 'project_id', 'type', 'unit']
converted_meters = [dict([(key, getattr(m, key, None))]) for m in meters for key in fields]
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame(converted_meters)
```